# Soundcloud Custom Player include buy button

Tags: jquery, soundcloud

Working on a player using http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player

Want to include a buy button like all the other Soundcloud embeds offer... not in the docs. Anybody have a hacky way to do so? It's running off the same API as the HTML5 widget, so I'm sure there's at least something that can be done.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every track object has a property `purchase_url` - external purchase link, if exists it should point to 'buy now' url.

check documentation here:

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/tracks

Comment: YES. had to get nasty, but that's exactly what I needed. Thank you.