# Change purchase title of soundCloud player

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

I use the script [php-soundcloud](https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud) (Oauth 2) and want to change the title (Buy this track) of purchase link.
I can update the link but I can not change the text of link.

[image: soundcloud purchase]

I use this code:

```
$soundcould->put('https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/56649403', array(
  'track[purchase_url]' => 'http://website.com/', 
  'track[purchase_title]' => 'Support me' // whitout this, it work
));
```

but it returns me an error: The requested URL responded with [HTTP code 422](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#errors).

When i remove `track[purchase_title]`, it work, so the problem is that variable!

Must be something special to change the link title?
Soundcloud have posed limits on the use of their API?
It's possible to create a new link other than changing the variable `purchase_title`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because the purchase_url and purchase_title can only be changed on premium accounts. I'll look at making this more clear in the docs!

Here's a code sample that will do the trick for a premium account:

```
<?php
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

$client = new Services_Soundcloud('client_id', 'client_secret', 'redirect_uri');
$client->setAccessToken('your-access-token');

$track_url = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/52652023.json';
$response = json_decode($client->put($track_url, array(
  'track[purchase_url]' => 'http://website.com',
  'track[purchase_title]' => 'Support me'
)));
?>
```

If that doesn't work, the problem is elsewhere. Email me and I can help you debug further.

Comment: I have a premium account! and I can change the `purchase_url` but not the `purchase_title` (get error 422)

Comment: That's definitely odd then. I'll edit my answer with a complete, tested code sample. Can you email me if it doesn't work? osman at soundcloud.com

Comment: Actually, it works! I do not know why my other code does not work! thank you very much for your precious help Paul ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try it. I think it is help full to you :-

**See the guide:-**

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide

**Try it**

```
<?php
$track = <<<EOH
<track>
    <downloadable>true</downloadable>
    <purchase_url>http://website.com/</purchase_url>
    <purchase_title>true</purchase_title>
</track>
EOH;

try {
    $response = json_decode(
        $soundcloud->put(
            'tracks/1',
            $track,
            array(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/xml'))
        ),
        true
    );
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: this will activate the link (it works with my code), but your code does not change the "title" of the link

Comment: try this xml in my code <track>
    <downloadable>true</downloadable>
    <purchase_url>http://website.com/</purchase_url>
    <purchase_title>support me</purchase_title>
</track>

Comment: exactly the same answer that my code! `The requested URL responded with HTTP code 422.` :/

Comment: without `purchase_title`, it work (your code)! I think it has to disable the ability to change this var

Comment: may be you are right. which account you have to use free or premium. may be possible this title can be change in premium account.

Comment: You can see this url https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud i think it is very help full to you. please read his instration its very necessary.

Comment: purchase_title variable dose not exist only purchase_url variable exist in soundcloud player. see the reference guide http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420970/soundcloud-custom-player-include-buy-button

Comment: thk Abid but I use the [API Console](http://developers.soundcloud.com/console) (work whit Oauth), I have no problem to retrieve the values, my script works very well, my only problem is to update the link title. All the links you gave me does not help me much but thank you even